# Generic error in pyspark - org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: index_not_found_exception: no such index

Tags: pyspark

Getting weird exceptions with pyspark during count and save of dataframe. Any specific reason for error is helpful.

[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]   File "/data/script_3658.py", line 147, in get_common_df
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]     print 'check count 5 ' + str(test.count())
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]   File "/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 522, in count
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]   File "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]   File "/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2]   File "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
[Control-Executor-2] py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o328.count.
[SCRIPT_3658_3660] [Control-Executor-2] : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
 Exchange hashpartitioning(trim(VSA_JOIN#2292, None), 8)
+- BatchEvalPython [(trim(VSA_PVSA_VSAM_ACP_CPBSYS_TC_TC_ORGN_NMBR#502, None)), (trim(VSA_PVSA_VSAM_ACP_CPBSYS_TC_TC_TYPE_NMBR#503, None))], [VSA_PVSA_VSAM_ACP_CPBSYS_TC_TC_ORGN_NMBR#502, VSA_PVSA_VSAM_ACP_CPBSYS_TC_TC_TYPE_NMBR#503, pythonUDF0#4571, pythonUDF1#4572]
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(pythonUDF0#4571, pythonUDF1#4572, 8)

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: index_not_found_exception: no such index

Comment: Please add an example of your code. Currently it looks like you're trying to save your dataframe to ElasticSearch, and index you're using is not there. Can you check if it actually exists?

Comment: I just updated the sample code here. Final merged dataframe some how is getting lost i guess. Its basically fails doing count or even while performing save to ElasticSearch.